# Testnet connections setup

Tags: nodeos

How should we setup connections between nodes in EOS blockchain (via `--p2p-peer-address`)?

1) all-to-all

```
1->2
1->3
..
1->21
2->1
2->3
2->4
...
2->21
...
21->20
```

2) chained (cycled)

```
1->2
2->3
3->4
...
20->21
21->1
```

3) Some 'true way' ?

What do you recommend?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The network-architecture of a production-network is different but I'd recommend you to read https://eosnation.io/eos-mainnet-update-new-node-architecture-greatly-improves-eos-reliability/ and https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/issues/8650 for a better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really matter on a local testnet, as long as each block production node is connected to the others through some method then everything will work. You have to consider what will happen if one of the producers goes down, for example if using method 2, and BP1 and BP14 go down, then it will be impossible to get irreversible blocks.

On the other hand, connecting every node to every other node is likely to be less performant